# X11 - handling XSelectionRequestEvent after calling XSetSelectionOwner

Tags: clipboard, x11, xlib

I implement clipboard handling in my X11 application. The first step of a copy operation is calling `XSetSelectionOwner:`

```
Atom clipboardAtom = XInternAtom(display, "CLIPBOARD", False);
XSetSelectionOwner(display, clipboardAtom, clipboardWin, CurrentTime);
```

After that I get `XSelectionRequestEvent`. That event contains target atom. Does calling `XSetSelectionOwner` always set target atom to atom "TARGETS" ?

```
Atom targetsAtom = XInternAtom(display, "TARGETS", False);
//handling XSelectionRequestEvent after calling XSetSelectionOwner
if(event.xselectionrequest.target == targetsAtom)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XSelectionRequestEvent` is the result of some other window (the `.requestor` field in the event) sending a [`ConvertSelection`](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XConvertSelection.html) request. It is up to the requestor to set the value of the `target` field.

The atom "TARGETS" is often (but not always) used by programs that support multiple types of selection. ICCCM [says](https://x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/specs/ICCCM/icccm.html#target_atoms) every selection owner must know how to answer this with the list of supported targets for this selection. The requestor will then decide what exact target to request if more than one is supported.

Not all clients will send `ConvertSelection` with the target set to "TARGETS". For example, a text editor or a terminal will just send "UTF8_STRING" or similar and hope for the best. A client that can deal with multiple target types is likely to send "TARGETS". Notable examples are clients that implement the clipboard functionality (xclipboard or your desktop environment equivalent).

Clipboard-like clients monitor selections and request info about it (and sometimes claim ownership) right after a selection changes. That's probably why you see `XSelectionRequestEvent` event(s) immediately after your window asserts a selection ownership. On a bare X server with no other clients, your window will never see any `SelectionRequest` events. If there are "regular" clients like text editors or terminal emulators, you will see `SelectionRequest` when one of those executes a paste command.

Comment: It's not clear for me what you mean by "it is up to the requestor to set the value of the target". After calling ```XSetSelectionOwner``` I get ```XSelectionRequestEvent```. I have thought that X Server sends that event and the behaviour is fixed.

Comment: @Irbis No, it is some client. See the update. A request is something that a client sends to the server. The server may notify other clients about this request by means of events. If you see an event named ...RequestEvent, that's an event sent by the server in response to some request by some client (the same one that receives the event or a different one).

Comment: Ok, but who is the "some" client ? I have checked and the requestor field in the ```XSelectionRequestEvent``` is different than the helper window for handling a clipboard (```clipboardWin```) passed as the argument to the ```XSetSelectionOwner```.

Comment: @Irbis It is not *your* window. It is a window of some other client that implements xclipboard-like functionality. On my Windows X server (one that I use for SSH connections to a Linux nachine), I get requests from a window named "xwinclip". On the Linux native server, the window is unnamed and unmapped with no parent, so I cannot tell where exactly it comes from, but it *must* be a client that monitors selections. It is likely to be an xclipboard-like client. Why do you need the exact identity of that client?

Comment: I don't need that information in my application. I have just wanted to know how that mechanism works.

Comment: The mechanism is described in the ICCCM reasonably well.